# Unable to resume Windows 10 after hibernation in a dual boot PC

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, hibernate

I left my PC turned on last night, in Windows session, and when I returned home it was off (I guess it was because of hibernation). So I turned it on again, logo of BIOS appeared as usual, GRUB options appeared as usual, but then, whether if I click on Windows or Ubuntu, the result is the same: A black screen and nothing happens after.

I have discovered that I can log into Ubuntu if I go to "repair options" and click on update grub option, but just once, because once I reboot PC, the same happens again. If I try to access Windows partitions while in Ubuntu, it says that they are hibernating (I had to do some process I can't remember to allow Ubuntu recognize them though).

I have tried reading about similar problems, but they all suggest logging into Windows and turning off hibernation, but I can't log into Windows.

Comment: " if I go to "repairs options" and click on update grub option, but just once, because once I reboot PC, the same happens again", what same  thing? You mean unable to boot into the windows? but still able to login to Ubuntu? or you are not able to login none of them?

Comment: Windows did an update in back ground & probably turned fast start up back on. Grub will not boot hibernated  Windows to prevent damage to system. Is this BIOS install? If BIOS you have to use your Windows repair/recovery disk to temporarily reinstall a Windows BIOS boot loader. If UEFI you can just boot directly into Windows using UEFI boot menu, often f10 or f12. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: I mean unable to boot into none of them. When I checked if fast start was enabled in BIOS menu It appeared as "disabled".. can it be enabled anyways without showing off?

Comment: Is UEFI btw, and Windows doesn't ley me start It that way (through boot menu).

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. But if UEFI will not boot Windows you have to use your Windows repair/recovery drive to fix it. You did make a Windows recovery drive? All computer systems need to have a way to boot in an emergency. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-options