# Windows option just reloads grub bootloader after updating to Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10, bootloader

I updated to Ubuntu 19.10 from 19.04. After updating, Ubuntu booted alright. The grub bootloader shows option for Ubuntu and Windows as it was before updating. But now, when I select Windows option, it just reloads the grub bootloader.

I tried boot-repair and many other things but nothing worked. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change your boot order to Windows instead of Grub. To find out the key to press during boot to bring up the BIOS menu see:

- [The computer didn't automatically boot from USB,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180675/the-computer-didnt-automatically-boot-from-usb/1180697#1180697)

Ignore the part about selecting device boot order, you want to change the UEFI boot order and move Windows to the top.

Then the instructions on `boot-repair` report tell you to boot into Windows and then:

> ```
> For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
> bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
> ```

Do this from Windows and then if it doesn't work revise your question with current status / new issues.

Also note boot-repair created 5 entries to boot Windows but in my experience they won't all work. After you fix the booting issues see this answer:

- [Boot-Repair created too many grub menu entries for Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938633/boot-repair-created-too-many-grub-menu-entries-for-windows/1022700#1022700)

Comment: Thanks, It worked. I can now boot into windows and all useless option from grub menu are removed. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows is in hibernation (see line 1112-1116 of Boot-Info summary). You need to boot into Windows and shut it down completely before you can boot it from grub. Try to select the Windows UEFI boot option in the bios or the bios boot menu. After you shut Windows down, you should be able to get it to boot from grub menu.

If you're unable to get Windows to boot this way, you'll probably need to repair the Windows boot loader with Windows recovery tools (lots of search results, but off topic here).

These links may help:

[Unable to resume Windows 10 after hibernation in a dual boot PC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963635/unable-to-resume-windows-10-after-hibernation-in-a-dual-boot-pc)

[The Pros and Cons of Windows 10's "Fast Startup" Mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/)

Fast Startup is called Fast Boot in Windows 8. I'd recommend disabling it (also disable in UEFI if there is an option there) to avoid future problems.